# Transform Apache Rules to Nginx

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx

i want to move Apache Web server to ngnix webserver but how i can change these Apache rules to ngnix.
i have one file of .htaccess in my main site and one in sub directory

main site .htacess
    
    RewriteEngine on

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ zzz.php?hash=$1   [L]
</IfModule>
```

in sub directory .htacess rules

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ host.php?hash=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: any help for me here **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44346456/apache-auth-rules-converted-for-nginx-server**

Answer (score 0):

Don't use rewrite rules for this in nginx, try_files is much faster:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
```

You can of course set as many items as you want and update script names, for example like this:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /$uri.php$is_args$args; /index.php$is_args$args =404;
```

Can be used in server or location section of nginx configuration:
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files

Nginx doesn't have something like .htaccess